# Shell script `rm -r`: Redirect write-protected prompt and answer "n"

Tags: shell-script, rm, prompt, error-handling

I have a few lines in a shell script whose function is to iterate through directories, match some names, and delete them. Some areas of the file system are write protected and **I would like to leave those alone but redirect the prompt or some other indication of the error into a log** when they are encountered.

Using `rm -r /path/to/directory` at that point in the script causes the script to output

```
rm: descend into write-protected directory /path/to/directory/subdirectory?
```

So it hangs and [eventually] times out when left to its own devices.

I attempted to correct this behavior by piping "n" to that prompt with

```
yes n | rm -rv /path/to/directory
```

This produces two undesired results:

1. Outputting `yes: standard output: Broken pipe; yes: write error` for every directory that *is* removed, and
2. Not returning the `rm: descend into write-protected...` message to stdout.

What is the right way to do this?

**Update:**
According to @roaima I am not actually piping `yes n` to the prompt at all because the existence of that pipe makes `rm` non-interactive. This is ironic because I was really exploiting the interactivity just to get some output but if I turn off interactivity the program will just exit in error. I don't want to ignore the error (e.g. by appending `|| true` as I have seen so many other places on SE) because I want the names of the protected files.

Comment: The message `rm: descend into write-protected...` is only generated by `rm` when it is interactive mode. By piping `yes n` into `rm` you are revoking its interactive option, so there is no longer any message to capture.

Comment: according to man, you can force interactive mode, however piping n will answer no to every file removal question, which is probably not what you want. you best try is `rm -rf` ( or `rm -rvf` )

Comment: @Archemar The desired result is to inform and not delete when it encounters problematic files. `rm -rf` will ignore them.

Comment: you still have rm: cannot remove '/my/dir/my/file.txt': Permission Denied when using rm -rf. my understanding is that you have too much of it.

Comment: "I want the names of the protected files." - can't you get these by just seeing what files are still there at the end?

Comment: A lot of filtering, pattern matching, exclusion, etc. happens on the (very large chunk of the) file system where this runs before it gets to this point. Looking back to see what made it to this point in the code and wasn't deleted would be almost as complex as running the script itself. Frankly, that is the reason I want this error message. Also, the files and directories present are likely to change daily.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest considering a different tool.
The 'find' command is very powerful and once you get past some of the syntax rules, easy to use.

Example:

```
find /directory -name pattern -perm g=w -exec /bin/rm {} \;
```

This will search for all files and sub folders under /directory that have the group permission of 'write' (logic match to 0020 octal chmod format) It would then erase that file.

Or you can run it with the print option and get a list of what files match the find pattern.

```
ex: find /directory -name pattern -perm 0111 -print
```

Comment: Working through your answer now. Why do I want `g=w` and not `u=w`? (I've never used `-perm` before.) I will test out `find` but I'm afraid it might be slow.

Comment: I was just using that as an example permission, you can use any of the possible permission flags you can use with 'chmod'

Comment: You should use `-delete`, not -exec /bin/rm. Neither g=w nor u=w works for me at all; find treats permissions differently from chmod - `/=w` works for this for me.

Comment: I found it - using `g=w` will only find files with permission of _exactly_ 020, rather than all files having it set. You can use `-g=w` or `/g=w` to find files with it set (`-ug=w` finds files with both user and group write, `/ug=w` finds files with either set.)

Comment: @Random832 How will `-delete` behave when it encounters a write-protected subdirectory? (I am hesitant to test it before knowing.) Specifically, if I use `find /directory -type d -perm /ug=w -delete` will it just skip those subdirectories or will it return a message about them? What if I leave out the `-perm` to force the error?

Comment: Replacing that line with `find...` increased the overall running time of the script by about 50%. This might be acceptable but I would prefer to do better.

Comment: It'll just skip them. But if you want you could just create an example tree to test on, with `touch` to create empty files and `chmod` to set whatever permission you want on files or directories. However, if you're not able to delete them because they're owned by someone else, you'll get a message.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` will ask for confirmation for non-writeable targets if stdin is a terminal. The `-i` flag on the other hand turns on confirmation for *all* targets. Clearly neither works with the simple solution of piping `yes n` to `rm`, so we must use something else.

Using GNU find, delete all objects that have at least one of the write-mode bits set (as usual, use `-print` instead of `-delete` at first to test):

```
find dir/ -perm /0222 -delete
```

---

Or, delete all files<sup>(*)</sup> with at least one write-mode bit set, but skip the contents of non-writeable directories :

```
find . -type d ! -perm /0222 -prune -o ! -type d -perm /0222 -exec rm {} +
```

<sup>(* actually everything but directories)</sup>

`-delete` implies a depth-first search (at least on GNU find), and doesn't work with `-prune`, so we can't use that here. We can delete empty writeable directories after that:

```
find . -type d -perm /0222 -delete
```

This will throw errors for nonempty directories.

`-perm /0222` stands for "any of the write bits are set", and its inverse `! -perm /0222` for "none of the write bits are set".

In other versions of find, use `+0222` instead of `/0222`. (According to the GNU manpage, the former conflicts with POSIX requirements and has been deprecated.)

---

To find the non-writeable files and directories, we can similarly use

```
find . ! -perm /0222
```

Recursively listing the contents of non-writeable directories is a bit harder to do, but with GNU tools this might work:

```
find . ! -perm /0222 -print0 | xargs -0 find
```