Remove all files, but write protected
In the folder there are files with write permission and without it. I need to remove only files which have write permission.
When I simply do rm * it prompts confirmation for every write-protected file, so if I answer NO, it works as I need. But I don't want to be asked every time, and just want to answer NO to all.
I created temporary file tmp with only n inside
echo n > tmp
and run rm * < tmp
I wait than this will work as sending NO automatically to rm, but it doesn't. It just removes all files without any prompt.
When I run rm -i * < tmp it prompts for every file (with write protection and without) and sends n there, so no files are removed, it works like expected.
I understand there are other ways to do this, but I want to figure out why rm * prompts for write-protected files, but rm * < tmp not? But rm -i * and rm -i * < tmp behave similar?

Perhaps duplicate of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355947/114435 . In Ikkachu's answer is explained exacly why you're being prompted or not depending on the circumnstances.

If you're open to using zsh, you could use a glob qualifier to match only regular files that are owner-writeable rm -- *(.w) (more complex permission specifications may be expressed with fspec)

If it does as expected confirming no, then rm -i * < tmp & echo 'n' | xdotool type --terminator ! --file - ! keydown Enter will automate it.

Using find:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name '.*' -perm -u=w -exec rm {} +


find .: finds all directories / files in the current working directory, recursively;
-maxdepth 1: limits the search recursion's depth to 1 level;
-type f: limits the results to files;
-not -name '.*': limits the results to non-dotfiles, to mimic the default * expansion's behavior;
-perm -u=w: limits the results to files that are at least writable by the owner;
-exec rm {} +: calls rm passing the results as a list of arguments


For convenience, you'll probably want to alias it to something like delete_writable in your ~/.bashrc (mind that .* is quoted differently here to prevent clashing with the outer single quotes):
alias delete_writable='find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name ".*" -perm -u=w -exec rm {} +'


% touch .hidden_writable writable non_writable
% chmod u-w non_writable                      
% ls -la
totale 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 29 02:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 user user     4096 apr 29 02:59 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user        0 apr 29 02:58 .hidden_writable
-r--rw-r--  1 user user        0 apr 29 02:58 non_writable
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user        0 apr 29 02:58 writable
% alias delete_writable='find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name ".*" -perm -u=w -exec rm {} +'
% delete_writable 
% ls -la
totale 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 apr 29 02:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 user user     4096 apr 29 02:59 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user        0 apr 29 02:58 .hidden_writable
-r--rw-r--  1 user user        0 apr 29 02:58 non_writable

